# Google new reCaptcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, contact-form

I made a simple form using the newest reCaptcha but I don't know how to block sending a form if captcha was wrong rewritten.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>reCaptcha</title>
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="validate.php" method="POST">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My public key"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" style="width:100px;height:20px">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</!DOCTYPE>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cancel default event from submit button, and submit form when data return is success.

`$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.post(//calling google api to verify it, 
            function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }
        );
    });`

Comment: Thank you very much! :) 

Can you edit my code and add your solution, please?


I don't know how can I use that: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: This is not a good way to check recaptcha since your method does not block robot actions. (submit the form by code)